# Associative-array in for loop using jQuery.post() results in only last entry being stored

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop, associative-array, .post

I am trying to pull down xml content from the server using **jQuery.post()** in a for loop on an list of multiple document names. Only the last response is being stored in the associative-array successfully while the other entries end up **undefined**.

```
var pagedata  = new Array () ;

loadpagexml = function ( liststring ) {
  var pagenames = liststring.split(',') ;

  for ( var i in pagenames ){
    xmltoget = pagenames[i]+'.xml' ;
    $.post( xmltoget , function(data) { 
      pagedata[ pagenames[i] ] = data ;
    }) ;
  }
}

var listofpages = 'poo,dung,corn' ;
loadpagexml ( listofpages )

>pagedata['poo']
  undefined
>pagedata['dung']
  undefined
>pagedata['corn']
  #document
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're suffering from a closure problem with your callback, so the captured value is always the last one form the loop, particularly because this is an async operation.

You should be able to do this:

```
(function(id, url)
{
    var idInternal = id;
    $.post(url, function(data)
    {
       pagedata[pagenames[idInternal]] = data;
    });
})(i, $xmlToGet);
```